# How can I get rid of " Skipped Frames. Application may be doing too much work on it's main thread" error

Tags: android

I am trying to run the first example of building my app and I get this error while staring another activity from the main activity. From System.out messages, I can see that the `sendMessage()` method is called by `onClick` of the Send Button, but the Display Message Activity never gets called.

The logcat has this messages -

```
"03-20 08:56:52.278: I/Choreographer(868): Skipped 66 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."
```

This gets printed until I kill the emulator.

Is this a memory issue? I'm using 4G Ram PC.

```
    MainActivity.java

    package com.example.firstproject;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import com.example.firstproject.DisplayMessageActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.firstproject.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) { // Do something in response to button
        System.out.println("Send message is called");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
         System.out.println("message =" + message);
    }

}


DisplayMessageActivity.java
----------------------------

     package com.example.firstproject;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;

    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("Hi Display is called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
       // Create the text view 
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message); 
        // Set the text view as the activity layout 
        setContentView(textView);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

AndroidManifest file


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you forgot actually starting the `DisplayMessageActivity`; add `startActivity(intent)` in `MainActivity.sendMesssage()`. Also see [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#StartActivity).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have omitted it somehow in my code, yes adding startActivity fixed it.